# Java polymorphism - How to determine whether superclass vs subclass method will be called and superclass variable vs subclass variable?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Example code:

```
public class A {

    public int number;

    public A(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

}



public class B extends A{

    public int number;

    public B(int number) {
        super(number);
    }


    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

}


public class C {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        A test1 = new B(2);
        B test2 = new B(2);

        System.out.println(test1.number) // prints 2
        System.out.println(test2.number) // prints 0
        System.out.println(test1.getNumber()) //prints 0
        System.out.println(test2.getNumber()) // prints 0
    }

}
```

As shown above test1.number is not equal to test1.getNumber().

So when I make test1 an object of type A test1.number is referring to the int number in class A.

But when I call test1.getNumber() it's calling getNumber() in class B?

Why does that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All methods in Java are virtual.  I'll get to what that means in a second.

So, on this line:

```
A test1 = new B(2);
```

You've assigned a new instance of class `B` to a variable declared as holding an `A`.

When you use `test1.number`, you're using the `number` variable declared in class `A`, which given that the constructor for `B` calls `super(number)` will be 2.

However, when you call `test1.getNumber()`, that's where the virtual kicks in.  Virtual means that it will always call a method in the constructed class rather than the type of variable that you've declared it as.  In other words, rather than calling `A`'s `getNumber` like you thought it would, it actually call's `B`'s `getNumber` instead.  `B`'s constructor doesn't assign a value to `B`'s `number` variable, so you get 0.

Comment: As a side note, it's bad practice to declare variables with the same names in both parent classes and child classes for this reason.

Comment: On another side note, if you ever use C#, it's syntax looks very similar to Java, but in C# you actually have to declare methods as `virtual` in the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

I found some information according to this website that explains class hierarchies in Java. 
When you extend a class, you're basically copying the code from that class and putting it into the one that extends it so you don't have to rewrite the methods, but you do in class B. So instead of using the method in class A it will use the one you coded into class B.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

That's because Java allows overriding for methods, but not for fields.

The spec [writes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3):

> If a class declares a field with a certain name, then the declaration of that field is said to hide any and all accessible declarations of fields with the same name in superclasses, and superinterfaces of the class.
>
> *In this respect, hiding of fields differs from hiding of methods (§8.4.8.3), for there is no distinction drawn between static and non-static fields in field hiding whereas a distinction is drawn between static and non-static methods in method hiding.*
>
> A hidden field can be accessed by using a qualified name (§6.5.6.2) if it is static, or by using a field access expression that contains the keyword super (§15.11.2) or a cast to a superclass type.
>
> *In this respect, hiding of fields is similar to hiding of methods.*

That is, each instance of `B` has two different fields that happen to share the same name. When you use a field name in an field access expression such as `test1.number`, the field name is interpreted with respect to the compile time type of `test1`.

In contrast, instance methods [can be overridden](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1):

> An instance method mC declared in (or inherited by) class C, overrides from C another method mA declared in class A, iff all of the following are true:
>
> - C is a subclass of A.
> - ...
> - The signature of mC is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of mA.

(where "subsignature" means that the method name and parameters are compatible.)

Overridding is [resolved as follows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.4):

> Otherwise, an instance method is to be invoked and there is a target reference. If the target reference is null, a NullPointerException is thrown at this point. Otherwise, the target reference is said to refer to a target object and will be used as the value of the keyword this in the invoked method.
>
> ...
>
> Otherwise, [...] overriding may occur. A dynamic method lookup is used. The dynamic lookup process starts from a class S, determined as follows:
>
> - If the invocation mode is interface or virtual, then S is initially the actual run-time class R of the target object.
> - ...
>
> The dynamic method lookup uses the following procedure to search class S, and then the superclasses and superinterfaces of class S, as necessary, for method m.

That is, if you write `test1.getNumber()`, the runtime will evaluate `test1` to get the target object, determine its class, and then look for a suitable method in that class.

In your example, `test1` references an object of class `B`, which is why `B.getNumber()` is invoked.

The implementation of `B.getNumber()` then proceeds to read `B.number`, which has never been assigned, and therefore still contains its default value 0.